# wcf response no deserializa soap

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Estoy pasando un servicio desde el antiguo marco 2.0 de referencia de servicio web. Ahora con .Net Core no logro deserializar la respuesta del endpoint. Alguien sabe cómo solucionar este error? Yo creo que falla la deserialización porque puedo ver con Fiddler que se ejecuta bien el request.

Este es el resultado que me retorna el endpoint y que debo deserializar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:getSeedResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace">
<ns1:getSeedReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">
   &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;SII:RESPUESTA 
 xmlns:SII=&quot;http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema&quot;&gt;&lt;SII:RESP_BODY&gt; &lt;SEMILLA&gt;075478838078&lt;/SEMILLA&gt;&lt;/SII:RESP_BODY&gt;&lt;SII:RESP_HDR&gt;&lt;EST 
 ADO&gt;00&lt;/ESTADO&gt;&lt;/SII:RESP_HDR&gt;&lt;/SII:RESPUESTA&gt;
   </ns1:getSeedReturn>
   </ns1:getSeedResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Así se ve con CDATA, el contenido es otro documento xml:

```
     <ns1:getSeedReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">
     <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SII:RESPUESTA 
     xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema"><SII:RESP_BODY><SEMILLA>075434993460</SEMILLA></SII:RESP_BODY>
     <SII:RESP_HDR><ESTADO>00</ESTADO></SII:RESP_HDR></SII:RESPUESTA>]]>
     </ns1:getSeedReturn>
```

El wfc me agrega una clase llamada "Reference", algo así:

```
public Seed.getSeedResponse getSeed(Seed.getSeedRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.getSeed(request); // return always nulll
}


[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")] 
[ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
      Semilla.getSeedResponse getSeed(Semilla.getSeedRequest request);
```

Así lo llamo:

```
CrSeedClient cliente = new();
getSeedRequest req = new();
string? token = cliente.getSeed(req).getSeedReturn; // return always nulll
```

Siempre retorna null desde el servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar actualizar la web reference desde Visual Studio. Cuando el cliente del webproxy recibe un elemento que no puede deserializar le asigna un valor por defecto, que es null.
¿Podrías mostrarnos el OperationContract de tu servicio y de tus DataContract?

Comment: Hola, he intentado configurar el proxy de dos maneras, con el check de "always generate msg contracts" y sin el y tampoco funciona. Con el antiguo marco no debía hacer nada más que importar el wsdl ahora hay que generar alguna clase custom?

Comment: Funcionó quitando esto: `[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults = true, Use = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]`